# No route to host : ssh Error

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have a laptop and a PC (me@172.16.13.151) , I usually connect the laptop to PC via ssh. But now when I try `ssh -X me@172.16.13.151` , it is showing the following error `ssh: connect to host 172.16.13.151 port 22: No route to host`. What could be the possible problem ?

Output of `ifconfig` is the following:

```
eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:41:38:0d:bb:a2
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:1750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:134949 (134.9 KB)  TX bytes:134949 (134.9 KB)

wlan0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:df:9a:76:18:1e
inet addr:172.16.101.213  Bcast:172.16.111.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
inet6 addr: fe80::d2df:9aff:fe76:181e/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:595855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:37917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:138691381 (138.6 MB)  TX bytes:4733835 (4.7 MB)
```

output of `route` is the following :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.96.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
172.16.96.0     *               255.255.240.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

Output of `traceroute 172.16.13.151` gives

```
traceroute to 172.16.13.151 (172.16.13.151), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
1  172.16.96.5 (172.16.96.5)  456.381 ms  457.461 ms  457.448 ms       
2  172.16.96.5 (172.16.96.5)  5007.656 ms !H  5007.665 ms !H  5015.906 ms !H
```

Comment: You can diagnose this further with `traceroute` command. Most likely your gateway router `172.16.96.1` is missing the route to `172.16.13.0/24` network.

Comment: Please edit debug output like this always into the question, it is difficult to read from the comments.

Comment: I've modified the question including the `traceroute` part

Comment: @TeroKilkanen If it was missing the route it shouldn't take 5 seconds to respond. More likely it does have a route and sends ARP queries for the destination. But nobody answers the ARP queries so after 5 seconds it times out.

Answer (score 1):

The source `172.16.101.213` and the destination `172.16.13.151` are not on the same network (based on the netmask `255.255.240.0`). Thus your laptop is sending the packets to the default gateway `172.16.96.1`, which apparently does not know the route to your PC.

Comment: `@Johan Myréen`I think you are making a mistake here `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference`, both source and destination are on the same network here . Subnet mask is `255.255.240.0` not `255.255.255.0`, both are different. Here the default gateway is the IP of the router and it should be able to find out the PC. Please correct me if I am wrong. I also don't think taht host and the destination has to be on the same network inorder for SSH connections.

Comment: In hex notation the netmask is `ff.ff.f0.00`, the source address is `ac.10.65.d5` and the destination address `ac.10.0d.97`. The first five hex digits should be equal for the addresses to be on the same subnet.

Comment: `@Johan Myréen` Thank you for correcting my mistake. But it is not  necessary that the host and the destination should be on the same network inorder for ssh connection, right ?

Comment: No, of course it's not necessary for the the source and destination to be on the same subnet, otherwise ssh would not go very far. I jumped to this conclusion based on that you had two similar addresses and just a default route in addition to that. Btw, what is the 172.16.96.5 address in your traceroute listing above?

Comment: `@Johan Myréen` Actually I'm using my college wifi here and the routers are DHCP servers. So the gateway changes as I move around.

Comment: Ok, here's one more wild guess: maybe the subnetworks don't "see" each other, and your PC and laptop were originally on the same subnetwork by pure luck.